# Are Python's timestamp and PHP's timestamp the same?

Tags: php, python, time, raspberry-pi, timestamp

I send data from my Raspberry Pi using Python to my website, which uses PHP. Now I want to compare the timstamp of Python using: `time.time()` with the timstamp of PHP, using `time()`.

Are these the same? Can I subtract them to get the time difference?

Is there any "better" way to measure the time difference?

Comment: They are the same if the time configured on both machines is the same (regardless of timezone).

Comment: If they run on different computers they'll most likely differ in a few seconds. Computer clocks are not that exact and even with a daily NTP sync a 10 second drift is not unusual.